# Is there any non-nilpotent group such that every subgroup is self normalizing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any non-nilpotent group $G$   such that for any proper nontrivial subgroup $H$,

$$N_G(H)=H\ ?$$

**Edit:**
Thanks to "ahulpke" and "Myself", We see that it is not possible for finite groups. Is there any answer for infinite case ?

Comment: Note that such group must automatically be simple. (Because simple says that $N_G(H) < G$.) Also if $[a,b] = 1$ then $\langle a,b\rangle \subseteq N_G(\langle a\rangle)$.

Comment: @Myself: Yes they are but I did not say "simple" to avoid $Z_p$.

Comment: Tarski monsters are examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would have to be a simple group (proper normal subgroups have a larger normalizer), in which all Sylow subgroups are of prime order (Sylow subgroups are nilpotent, so the normalizer of a proper subgroup in it is larger than the subgroup.)
But there is a theorem (Burnside I think) that such a group would be solvable -- contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Note that such a group would be simple; moreover any subgroup of such a group would be simple for the same reason: if $H<X<G$ then $N_X(H) = N_G(H) \cap X = H\cap X = H$.

When dealing with finite groups that only leaves the cyclic groups of prime order, but these are nilpotent.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be an cooment.

Comment: Yes it is an answer.

Comment: After making a change, yes it seems to be.

Comment: for a infinite group, any idea ?